# Python 3.9.1 iterate lst to pass to tst2

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, conditional-statements, index-error

I want to read all the elements from a list, `lst`, check the value, change for a number and save in another list, `lst2`.

```
lst = ['a','b','c'] 
lst2 = []

for x in range(len(lst)): 
    if lst[x] == 'a': 
        lst2[x] == 1
    if lst[x] == 'b':
        lst2[x] == 2
    if lst[x] == 'c':
        lst2[x] == 3

print(lst2)
```

Error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range.
```

I already tried with while loop and I get the same message.
Can I achieve this in other way?

Comment: use lst2.append(1) instead of `==`. The `==` operator is to check for True and False

Comment: you need to replace `lst2[x] == 1` with `lst2.append(1)`

Comment: `lst2.append( 1)`, and so on. You can't assign anything to `lst[x]` if there is no item at index `x` in it - note that this would potentially allow you to create lists with 'holes' if it were possible, not a good idea...

Comment: If your intent is to have `lst2` be the same size that `lst1` was, then you can just initialize it to the proper size:  `lst2 = [None] * len(lst1)`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille heh, see: JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fill `lst2` with some values in order for the subscription assignments to work:

```
lst = ['a','b','c'] 
lst2 = [None] * len(lst)

for x in range(len(lst)): 
    if lst[x] == 'a': 
        lst2[x] = 1
    if lst[x] == 'b':
        lst2[x] = 2
    if lst[x] == 'c':
        lst2[x] = 3

print(lst2)
```

Where `[None] * len(lst)` returns `[None, None, None]`.

Of course, there's the [`list.append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method, which would be really handy if you can be sure that the values use will be added in consecutive indices.